# How to copy an object without linking it to the first one?

Tags: python, linked-data

I would like to copy an object without it remaining connected to the first, in the sense that I would like it to be independent (not linked)
I've been looking for a long time but I can't find anything about it, the current method I'm trying is:

example on default delected cube

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
new_ob = ob.copy()
new_ob.location.x = ob.location.x + 3
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_ob)
```

But this creates problems for me, since it remains linked to the first cube, I would like the second cube to become independent of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply copied the object data block, but it remained linked to the same mesh data block.

[image: linked user]

After copying the object datablock with `new_ob = ob.copy()`, add a line to copy the datablock.

```
new_ob.data = ob.data.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks Leander, I was just looking for exactly that